# How to recover from wiping by dd a partition table on external disk?

Tags: disk, data-recovery, dd

Yesterday I used `dd` to write an OS into my Raspberry Pi flash card. Even though all my commands ( I checked history ) were for `/dev/sdd` which was the flash , when I checked my external drive(500GB) there were only 2 partitions there, one of 3 GB and one of 15MB instead of all my precious data.

Is there any way to recover from that ? Cause, theoretically my data is still there. Or shall I just start crying ?

This is the command I ran:

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=~/Downloads/RetroPieImage_ver1.2.1.img of=/dev/sdd
```

Comment: Which commands did you run?

Comment: sudo dd bs=4M if=~/Downloads/RetroPieImage_ver1.2.1.img of=/dev/sdd

Comment: Did you double check your mistake? Have you validated that the image indeed was not written to the Pi? Isn't the HDD issue a coincidental problem? When checking the HDD's partition table, did you not accidentally look at `/dev/sdd`? Not to give false hope, but panic begets foolish mistakes.

Answer (score 6):

With that dd command you have lost some data.

You can try to recover data using [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) and/or [photorec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec)

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk
```

photorec is part of the testdisk package

[Here](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step) is a step by step tutorial

See also: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery