# My ubuntu is corrupted

Tags: 14.04, grub2, data-recovery, badblocks

I have a dual boot - Ubuntu and windows 7. I recently wass playing around in the ubuntu and used the 'dd' command and it kinda corrupted my linux file system. I exactly dont know what happened to Linux now. All my data is missing. I did the boot-repair and now the grub is removed and it is directly booting to windows. Please help me recover all my data in ubuntu. It is very important. Please help me with the process. I am desperate!!

Here is the pastebin link containing the logs.

[paste.ubuntu.com/11395840/](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11395840/)

Thanks in advance

Comment: What dd command did you use, to try and do what? You probably overwrote the system drive using dd, and it likely will be difficult to recover depending on the operation done. See also: http://askubuntu.com/q/264374/178596

Comment: Dude u r god !! thanks a lot. that is exactly what i also did and that corrupted my system .I am seeing that answer only now ! THanks

Answer (score 0):

You could [create a live Ubuntu USB or DVD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install), boot into it, then use the file manager to attempt to locate your home folder on your botched partition. If it's readable, you should be able to access it from the "Devices" section of the file manager sidebar. Copy the files onto an external drive, then reinstall Ubuntu. Then re-copy the files into the appropriate locations in your new home folder. All of your settings that aren't stored in the home folder will be lost, but at least you'll have your data.

You might be able to do it without the Ubuntu live disk by simply booting into Windows and [copying out the files from there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/379356/how-to-access-ubuntu-files-in-windows-7-while-having-dual-boot), but I've never tried it.

Comment: Settings located in the home folder are not lost. And this is Ubuntu. Maybe you should remove the untested Windows part