# External harddisk formatted recovery

Tags: 16.04, data-recovery

I was trying to make a bootable usb stick but i accidently formatted my 1TB hard disk. Is there a way to recover my files. The command that i used for formatting my disk

```
 sudo dd if=ubuntu-gnome-15.10-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdc bs=1M
```

Comment: Please refer to [How to recover from wiping by dd a partition table on external disk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/264374/how-to-recover-from-wiping-by-dd-a-partition-table-on-external-disk) and [I accidentally deleted all my data with `dd`. Any chance of recovery?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549790/i-accidentally-deleted-all-my-data-with-dd-any-chance-of-recovery)

Answer (score -1):

You could try testdisk or other partition recovery program. You probably lost some data.
You can follow this tutorial:
[testdisk tutorial](https://www.maketecheasier.com/recover-data-and-partitions-for-free-with-testdisk/)
else sources:
[similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94421/is-there-a-way-to-recover-files-from-a-storage-device-partially-overwritten-with?lq=1)